# Пользователь вводит 10 целых чисел в диапазоне от 0 до 9 Программа выводит количество каждого числа из введенных

Tags: c++

Пользователь вводит 10 целых чисел в диапазоне от 0 до 9 (числа могут повторяться). Программа выводит количество каждого числа из введенных. Если какое-то число из заданного диапазона не было введено пользователем ни разу, то информацию о нем выводить не нужно.

Comment: не пишите, код, просто объясните как можно это сделать

Comment: Диапазон всего 10? так воспользуйтесь массивом из 10 элементов для определения количества вводов каждого из чисел диапазона. Думаю, этого намека должно хватить с головой...

Comment: Можно отсортировать массив и через цикл сравнить элемент N с элементом N+1 и если они равны то присвоить их значение какой либо переменной(как вариант)

Comment: Сделайте map<int, int>. Каждый раз, получив от пользователя число x, сделайте m[x]++

Answer (score 1):

Заведите массив из десяти элементов по одному для каждой цифры - `int counters[10]`. Не забудьте обнулить содержимое этого массива. По мере поступления ввода, увеличивайте соответствующий счётчик на единицу. В конце выведите результат, пропуская нули.

```
const int ITEMS_TOTAL = 10;
const int DECIMAL_DIGITS = 10;

// Объявить массив и инициализировать его нулями.
int counters[DECIMAL_DIGITS] = {};
for (int i = 0; i < ITEMS_TOTAL; i++) {
    // Прочитать очередную цифру.
    int digit = -1;
    cin >> digit;
    if (digit < 0 || digit >= DECIMAL_DIGITS) {
        // Выйти в случае ошибки ввода.
        break;
    }
    // Увеличить очередной счётчик.
    counters[digit]++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < DECIMAL_DIGITS; i++) {
    if (counters[i] > 0) {
        // Вывести непустой результат.
        cout << i << '\t' << counters[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```